# Listening to attached Component.onCompleted and Component.onDestroyed signals from C++ Q_OBJECT

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-signals

I have a C++ `Q_OBJECT` (registered with `qmlRegisterType`) that I'd like to perform some actions on `Component.onCompleted` and `Component.onDestroyed`.

Is there a way to subscribe to those handlers without writing any QML?

It looks like I could use `QQmlEnginePrivate::registerFinalizeCallback`, but it would depend on private headers.

Comment: If you realize that depends on the Component that creates the object in QML, not the QObject, that is, the Component creates an object and adds it to the scene, the QObject does not know at what moment it started to be added to the scene if when finished. So for me it is impossible

Comment: Ok. I wonder if there is a trick I could do with attached properties. Maybe create an attached property for my object, when it is called, reach out to the QQmlComponent attached property and listen to it's signal?

Comment: FYI, this is what I'm trying to achieve. https://github.com/qmlnet/qmlnet/issues/101

Comment: The question is that onCompleted can be notified to the QObject since for the component to complete its task the object had to be created, but the onDestroyed I think it is not possible because the QObject was already destroyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with [`QQmlParserStatus`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlparserstatus.html)

> To use QQmlParserStatus, you must inherit both a QObject-derived class and QQmlParserStatus, and use the Q_INTERFACES() macro.

```
class MyObject : public QObject, public QQmlParserStatus
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QQmlParserStatus)

public:
    MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);
    ...
    void classBegin() override;
    void componentComplete() override;
}
```

`classBegin` can be useful to mark that an instance has been created from QML. It can make sense to do some initialization in `componentComplete` if it has been created from QML but do nothing if it has been created from c++.

As for the onDestroyed, you can connect something to the [`QObject::destroyed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal.
Note that when `destroyed` is emitted your object is just a `QObject`, all the subclasses' destructors have already been called.